# Translating an English statement to it's logical equivalent: "No student is friendly but not helpful"

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I am curious about the correct interpretation of the following English sentence in predicate logic. I suppose, I may also have to ask an English grammarian.

Let the following predicates be given. The domain consists of all people.

$F(x) = x$ is friendly

$H(x) = x$ is helpful

$S(x) = x$ is a student

Express the following English sentence in terms of $F(x)$, $H(x)$, $S(x)$, quantifiers, and logical connectives.

"*No student is friendly but not helpful.*"

Is it:

**A**

> $¬∃x(S(x) ∧ F(x) ∧ ¬H(x))$
>
> There does not exist a person such that that person is a student, that
> person is friendly, and that person is not helpful.

or

**B**

> $∀x( S(x) → (¬F(x)∧H(x))$
>
> that person is not friendly and helpful. For all people if a person is a student then

#### FOLLOW UP

> *It may be useful to note the ambiguity in the English*, which is clarified by the first comment on my posting to the ***English Grammar & Usage*** stack exchange, linked [HERE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/225323)

Comment: I'm trying to make sense in whatever language I know of "No student is friendly but not helpful" yet I can't: does it mean that no student is friendly and is also not helpful, or perhaps that whoever is a student can't be both unfriendly and not helpful...or something else? This indeed seems more like a grammatic question, as you say.

Comment: "A but B" is $A \land B$; thus "friendly but not helpful" is correctly translated as $F(x) \land \lnot H(x)$.

Comment: Please not that A. is equivalent to B' : $∀x(S(x) \to (\lnot F(x) \lor H(x)))$.

Comment: Who says "A but B" $\;=A\vee B\;$ ? I mean, is that defined somewhere?

Comment: We always take "A but B" to be equivalent to "A and B" i.e. A ∧ B

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I believe that ¬∃x(S(x) ∧ F(x) ∧ ¬H(x)) ≡ ∀x(S(x) ⟶ (¬F(x) ∨ H(x)) (there is OR, not AND in the second statement in the implication. Here's my logic: ∀x¬(S(x) ∧ F(x) ∧ ¬H(x)) ≡ ∀x(¬S(x) ∨ ¬(F(x) ∧ ¬H(x))) ≡  ∀x(S(x) ⟶ ¬(F(x) ∧ ¬H(x))) ≡ ∀x(S(x) ⟶ (¬F(x) ∨ ¬¬H(x))) ≡ ∀x(S(x) ⟶ (¬F(x) ∨ H(x))

Answer (score 1):

Note: $\;\neg \big(F(x) \wedge \neg H(x)\big) \iff \big(\neg F(x)\vee H(x)\big)\;$  by DeMorgan's Laws.

---

Now $\;\neg \exists x\, \big(S(x)\wedge F(x)\wedge \neg H(x)\big)\;$ parses as: "there is nothing that is a student and friendly and not helpful," or more naturally: "no student is friendly and/but not helpful."   Which is what you were required to express.

So applying dual negation, DeMorgan's law, and implication equivalence to this actually produces: $\;\forall x\, \Big(S(x) \;\to\; \big(\neg F(x)\vee H(x)\big)\Big)\;$, which parses as "if anything is a student then it is not friendly or it is helpful," or "any student either is not friendly or is helpful."

Alternatively, the equivalent, $\;\forall x\, \Big(S(x) \;\to\; \neg \big(F(x)\wedge \neg H(x)\big)\Big)\;$, reads, somewhat awkwardly as, "any student is not both friendly and not helpful".

I'd stay with the first form of the expression; as it say what you want in a way that is most compatible with natural language.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that when you wrote an English sentence corresponding to A, you had (more or less) the same English sentence with which you began.

Also notice that statement B says that if a person is a student, that person is not friendly, which your original sentence did not imply (and which we hope is not true!).

(This would be more appropriate in a comment, but I haven't the reputation.)